# Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android App using Xamarin on Visual Studio.

But I am getting this error on deploying application on phone:

> Unhandled Exception: Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:

It is occurring on a specific page , on "Services" line 43 
[image]

Before changing UI in serviceScreen , application was working fine.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0ffa0"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="73.7dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:background="#ecf1b7">
            <TextView
                android:text="ICICI SERVICES"
                android:layout_width="214.3dp"
                android:layout_height="43.3dp"
                android:id="@+id/serviceText"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="27dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/services"
                android:layout_width="64.0dp"
                android:layout_height="53.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/servicesLogo"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="#414347"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Button" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/personaldetails2"
                android:layout_width="97.0dp"
                android:layout_height="89.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/servicePersonal"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/carddetails"
                android:layout_width="98.7dp"
                android:layout_height="87.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/serviceCard"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/fundtransfer"
                android:layout_width="95.0dp"
                android:layout_height="87.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/serviceFund"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/billpayment"
                android:layout_width="97.7dp"
                android:layout_height="95.7dp"
                android:id="@+id/serviceBill"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/accountdetails"
                android:layout_width="95.0dp"
                android:layout_height="87.0dp"
                android:id="@+id/serviceAccount"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/transactionhistory"
                android:layout_width="85.3dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/serviceTransaction"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70.0dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/serviceBranch"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="#414347"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="74.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:background="#ecf1b7">
            <TextView
                android:text="*Back Functionality has been Disabled"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="23.7dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:background="#414347"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:layout_width="3dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="39dp" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/easeofaccess"
                android:layout_width="64.7dp"
                android:layout_height="53.3dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:background="#ecf1b7"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

C# File

```
using System;    
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Widget;

    namespace Hackathon_ICICI
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Services")]
        public class Services : Activity
        {
            MainSpeaker speaker = new MainSpeaker();
            //string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData") ?? "Data not available";

            public override void OnBackPressed()
            {
                //base.OnBackPressed();
                speaker.Main_speaker("This functionality has been disabled.");
            }

            protected override void OnRestart()
            {
                base.OnRestart();
                speaker.Main_speaker("Please select the service you would like to know about.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("View Personal Details.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("Card Details.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("Account Details.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("Transaction Details");
                //speaker.Main_speaker("Branch Details.");
            }

            protected override void OnPause()
            {
                base.OnPause();
                //speaker.Main_speaker("I've been PAUSED!");
                // Code can be added here to stop the MainSpeaker Class!
            }

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.servicesScreen);
                speaker.Main_speaker("Welcome to ICICI Special Services. Please select the service you would like to know about.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("View Personal Details.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("Card Details.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("Account Details.");
                speaker.Main_speaker("Transaction Details");
                //speaker.Main_speaker("Branch Details.");

                // Create your application here

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: can you help me now ?

Comment: Keep looking further on in your log. There's got to be more information than just the Unhandled Exception line.

Comment: just quick thing to check. Is the build action of the layoutxml file set to AndroidResource?

Comment: yes , it is set to Android Resource

Comment: The other one to check is the size of the images you are using. As you have a large amount of ImageButtons, I would suggest removing them to see if any are causing the issue

Comment: i reduced the size of images , that solved the issue . 
I dont understand , they were of at max 500 kb , but I reduced them to 50 kb or less.
How can it crash by using images using such small image size , I saw apps heavier than this !

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the Image size solved the Issue .